# Test Dependency Injection scope "coherence" with xUnit

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, dryioc

In an AzureFunction, I register some services as scoped and some other as Singleton.
It turned out that a dependency of a Singleton was a Scoped service (a bad thing) and at runtime I get [this kind of exception](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4452).

I would like to be able to write an unit test to check the same thing as the runtime but I did not manage to succeed. Anyone can help me ?

What I tried:

```cs
 // Arrange
var functionStartup = new MyFunctionStartup();
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var functionHostBuilder = A.Fake<IFunctionsHostBuilder>();
A.CallTo(() => functionHostBuilder.Services).Returns(serviceCollection);

// Act

// doing in fact under the hood:  
//  services.AddSingleton<ISingleton, Singleton>();
//  services.AddScoped<IScopedDependencyOfSingleton, ScopedDependencyOfSingleton>();
functionStartup.Configure(functionHostBuilder);


// Assert
var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

var singleton = provider.GetService<ISingleton>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an underlying DryIoc `IContainer` from the service provider and `Validate` for the captive dependency in a singleton:

```cs
var container = provider.GetRequiredService<IContainer>();
var errors = container.Validate(ServiceInfo.Of<ISingleton>());
if (errors.Count > 0) 
{
    // handle errors
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/ErrorDetectionAndResolution.md#service-registrations-diagnostics) for Validate.

Comment: It's working thanks ! Strange thing, dependency of scoped scope are registered as ScopedOrTransient in my xunit while the runtime register them as Scoped.

Comment: ScopedOrTransient? or do you mean ScopedOrSingleton?